# Can't Use Context API while making a tree

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I'm trying to make a tree and use context API so all nodes of the tree can call the parent function.

Here is the begining of my tree

```
<Filter>
    {dataSource.map((x, i) => {
        return <DataTree
            key={i}
            name={x.name}
            type={x.type}
            children={x.children}
        />
    })}
</Filter>
```

Here is my tree node

```
function DataTree(props) {

    const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false)

    return (
        <div className="mt-3">
            <div className="row">
                {props.children &&
                    <button className="btn-primary mr-2" onClick={() => setIsOpen(!isOpen)}>+</button>
                }
                <h5 onClick={() => props.setFilter(props.name, props.type)}>{props.name}</h5>
            </div>
            <h1>{JSON.stringify(props.filters)}</h1>
            <div className="pl-5">
                <Filter>
                    {isOpen && props.children && props.children.map((x, i) => {
                        return <DataTree
                            key={i}
                            name={x.name}
                            type={x.type}
                            children={x.children}
                        />
                    })}
                </Filter>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default withFilter(DataTree)
```

Here is my HOC for the context API

```
const FilterContex = React.createContext()

export function Filter(props) {

    const [filters, setFilters] = useState({})

    const addToFilter = (value, name) => {
        setFilters({ ...filters, [name]: value })
    }

    return (
        <FilterContex.Provider value={{ filters, setFilter: addToFilter }}>
            {props.children}
        </FilterContex.Provider>
    )
}

export function withFilter(Component) {
    return function FilterComponent(props) {
        return (
            <FilterContex.Consumer>
                {context => <Component {...props} {...context} />}
            </FilterContex.Consumer>
        )
    }
}
```

The problem is that Inside my `DataTree` the `DataTree` that I'm rendering isn't the one with `withFilter` so only the first node of the tree have the context API.

How can I render the `DataTree` with `withFilter` inside it self?
Also, I'm not sure if I'm making things right to make the context API work.

Comment: You need to use the context you pass down to `DataTree` with e.g. `useContext`.

Comment: How? Please Explain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using hooks, its better to go with hooks as a pattern instead of HOCs. So you solution will include using `useContext` hook to access context within your component

**DataTree**

```
function DataTree(props) {

    const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false)
    const {filters, setFilter} = useContext(FilterContex);
    return (
        <div className="mt-3">
            <div className="row">
                {props.children &&
                    <button className="btn-primary mr-2" onClick={() => setIsOpen(!isOpen)}>+</button>
                }
                <h5 onClick={() => setFilter(props.name, props.type)}>{props.name}</h5>
            </div>
            <h1>{JSON.stringify(filters)}</h1>
            <div className="pl-5">
                <Filter>
                    {isOpen && props.children && props.children.map((x, i) => {
                        return <DataTree
                            key={i}
                            name={x.name}
                            type={x.type}
                            children={x.children}
                        />
                    })}
                </Filter>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default DataTree;
```

---

**Filter API**

```
export const FilterContex = React.createContext()

export function Filter(props) {

    const [filters, setFilters] = useState({})

    const addToFilter = (value, name) => {
        setFilters({ ...filters, [name]: value })
    }

    return (
        <FilterContex.Provider value={{ filters, setFilter: addToFilter }}>
            {props.children}
        </FilterContex.Provider>
    )
}
```

---

If you want to know how you can achive the same with HOC, you would need to create a new connected DataTree component and use it for nested rendering

```
function DataTree(props) {

    const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false)
    return (
        <div className="mt-3">
            <div className="row">
                {props.children &&
                    <button className="btn-primary mr-2" onClick={() => setIsOpen(!isOpen)}>+</button>
                }
                <h5 onClick={() => props.setFilter(props.name, props.type)}>{props.name}</h5>
            </div>
            <h1>{JSON.stringify(props.filters)}</h1>
            <div className="pl-5">
                <Filter>
                    {isOpen && props.children && props.children.map((x, i) => {
                        return <DataTreeWithFilter
                            key={i}
                            name={x.name}
                            type={x.type}
                            children={x.children}
                        />
                    })}
                </Filter>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

const DataTreeWithFilter = withFilter(DataTree);
export default DataTreeWithFilter;
```